# Composing 2 (or n) ('a -> unit) functions with same arg type

Tags: f#, action, composition, side-effects, function-composition

Is there some form of built-in / term I don't know that kinda-but-its-different 'composes' two `'a -> unit` functions to yield a single one; e.g.:

```
let project event =
    event |> logDirections
    event |> stashDirections
let dispatch (batch:EncodedEventBatch) =
    batch.chooseOfUnion () |> Seq.iter project
```

might become:

```
let project = logDirections FOLLOWEDBY stashDirections
let dispatch (batch:EncodedEventBatch) =
    batch.chooseOfUnion () |> Seq.iter project
```

and then:

```
let dispatch (batch:EncodedEventBatch) =
    batch.chooseOfUnion () |> Seq.iter (logDirections FOLLOWEDBY stashDirections)
```

I guess one might compare it to `tee` (as alluded to in [FSFFAP's Railway Oriented Programming series](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/)).

(it needs to pass the same arg to both and I'm seeking to run them sequentially without any exception handling trickery concerns etc.)

(I know I can do `let project fs arg = fs |> Seq.iter (fun f -> f arg)` but am wondering if there is **something built-in and/or some form of composition lib I'm not aware of**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `apply` function from Klark is the most straightforward way to solve the problem.

If you want to dig deeper and understand the concept more generally, then you can say that you are *lifting* the sequential composition operation from working on *values* to work on *functions*.

First of all, the `;` construct in F# can be viewed as sequential composition operator. Sadly, you cannot quite use it as one, e.g. `(;)` (because it is special and lazy in the second argument) but we can define our own operator instead to explore the idea:

```
let ($) a b = a; b
```

So, `printfn "hi" $ 1` is now a sequential composition of a side-effecting operation and some expression that evaluates to `1` and it does the same thing as `printfn "hi"; 1`.

The next step is to define a lifting operation that turns a binary operator working on values to a binary operator working on functions:

```
let lift op g h = (fun a -> op (g a) (h a))
```

Rather than writing e.g. `fun x -> foo x + bar x`, you can now write `lift (+) foo bar`. So you have a point-free way of writing the same thing - just using operation that works on functions.

Now you can achieve what you want using the `lift` function and the sequential composition operator:

```
let seq2 a b = lift ($) a b
let seq3 a b c = lift ($) (lift ($) a b) c
let seqN l = Seq.reduce (lift ($)) l
```

The `seq2` and `seq3` functions compose just two operations, while `seqN` does the same thing as Klark's `apply` function.

It should be said that I'm writing this answer not because I think it is useful to *implement* things in F# in this way, but as you mentioned railway oriented programming and asked for deeper concepts behind this, it is interesting to see how things can be *composed* in functional languages.

Comment: +1 Thanks - I was hoping you might be able to read my mind like that. I love this language (and that *C# : F# :: Jon Skeet : Tomas Petricek*). In general, I don't sweat defining local functions to sugar things like this in F# but it just seemed there should be something for this. I guess I'll accept despite this not resolving my desire for there to be something for composing of side-effecting functions in a functional language :D (Seriously, I know it's a bad idea and not a common thing)

Answer (score 3):

Can you just apply an array of functions to a given data?
E.g. you can define:

```
let apply (arg:'a) (fs:(('a->unit) seq)) = fs |> Seq.iter (fun f -> f arg)
```

Then you will be able to do something like this:

```
apply 1 [(fun x -> printfn "%d" (x + 1)); (fun y -> printfn "%d" (y + 2))]
```

Comment: +1 Nothing wrong with the answer, but I should have been more explicit that how to define a helper isn't my question, it's *can I avoid* defining a helper.